# How to generate a mesh based on MakeHuman model

Tags: mesh, blender-internal-render-engine, makehuman

I am using a makeHuman to model different body person. I am wondering if it is possible to generate a mesh by sampling this model on cube or triangle or any other geometric form. Is this suggestion make sense? it it is not. How can generate a human mesh? Thanks

Comment: did you try the import plugin? it is included but not enabled by default. It should be able to create a blender model (mesh) from a mhx file

Comment: @m.ardito, In fact, I need a mesh to import it to Matlab or mathematica to process it

Comment: @startingBlender Does the answer you posted answer your question? If not, could you explain what you want in more detail?

Comment: @someonewithpc, yes it answer my question

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about Blender.

Comment: @someonewithpc, bravo!?

Answer (score 1):

We can export the MakeHuman model as .STL file and after that , we can easily Import a 3D model from STL as a MeshRegion object in mathematica
[How to import an 3D model from .STL file as meshregion on mathematica](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/STL.html)

[image]